# Picker dialog without Picker Component in React Native

Tags: react-native, picker

Can I use only dialog from `Picker` without rendering `Picker` itself in React Native 0.48? I want to open `Picker`'s list on button click. There's an obvious way creating a hidden `Picker` and rerouting clicks to it, but is it the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#actionsheet-def-headref

native base provide ui kit for react native. You look actionSheet section.

Comment: It's an option, but looks not the same as `Picker`'s dialog. Is there a way to use the very this modal window?

Comment: just you can such plugins: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialogs etc...

if you dont want use plugins, you should use react native core picker. Already you can use you want.